# Monior network throttling limits in Azure (kubernetes cluster)?

Tags: azure, networking, kubernetes

I am seeing slow download performance when doing many small get requests (NPM install) on my machines in a kubernetes cluster in Azure.

I found this article regarding GET/POST limits:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/request-limits-and-throttling#network-throttling

and have tried to navigate the portal to find some way to monitor if I am hitting these limits during the GET tasks I am running.

Is there anyway to monitor if those limits are being reached in the Azure Portal?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple methods to [enable monitoring of Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) cluster already deployed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/insights/container-insights-enable-existing-clusters#enable-directly-from-aks-cluster-in-the-portal). In the **Kubernetes services** portal, you can select **Monitor Containers** on the **Onboarding to Azure Monitor for containers** page.

Azure Monitor provides a multi-cluster view that shows the health status of all monitored Kubernetes clusters running Linux and Windows Server 2019 deployed across resource groups in your subscriptions. You also could view performance directly from a cluster and container metrics in metrics explorer. Read more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/insights/container-insights-analyze#view-container-metrics-in-metrics-explorer).

For more information, see [Best practices for application developers to manage resources in Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/developer-best-practices-resource-management).